# how to manage old pinescript scripts files in trading view?

Tags: pine-script

Does pinescript offer a way to manage a large number of old scripts?

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

[1] I did not see a way to organize scripts into folders?
[2] I did not see a way to download old scripts to my local windows machine?
[3] All I see you can do is delete old scripts. But, even through there are old, I prefer to keep a backup of them.

Answer (score 0):

No, Tradingview does not offer such features at the moment.

You need to copy your scripts and save them locally. Then you can delete your old scripts.